# How to get eclipse Shared images in RCP application?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I tried to access the eclipse shared images using:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages().getImage(ISharedImages.IMG_OBJ_PROJECT);
```

but it returned null! I also tried **IDE.SharedImages.IMG_OBJ_PROJECT** instead of **ISharedImages.IMG_OBJ_PROJECT** but no use it still returns null.
So how to get the shared images in eclipse RCP application?

Comment: Do you have `org.eclipse.ui` (which contains the icons) included in your RCP?

Comment: yes !
i have added it as dependency!

Comment: @greg-449 i think i know the reason, i am creating the workbench, so PlatforUI.getWorkbenh is referring to workbench i created i guess!<br/>
How to get the shared images in eclipse, i want the project image in my rcp app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ISharedImages.IMG_OBJ_PROJECT` is deprecated and returns null, the non-deprecated values in `ISharedImages` work.

For the project image `IDE.SharedImages.OBJ.PROJECT` can be used but **only** if you are using a workbench advisor based on `IDEWorkbenchAdvisor` which adds the IDE shared images.